# Very strange problem about NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

A very strange behavior about this function,

```
void* getNSString(const NSString* str){

str = @"This is new test";
//NSString* str1 = @"so strange test";

return;
}
```

Then

```
NSLog(@"%@",getNSString(@"test"));
```

The result will be

```
This is new test
```

if uncomment

```
NSString* str1 = @"so strange test";
```

My understanding is that nothing is returned, so that should be NULL , why print out those string ?

Then result will be

```
so strange test
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe that *nothing* is returned. I believe that it's undefined. In other words, anything could be returned.

In this case, it looks like it's returning whatever happened to be on the stack at a given location. That happens to be one of the strings you modified or created but I can assure you this is a fortunate accident (or unfortunate since a crash would probably be better).

If you want nothing to be returned, you need to change:

```
void* getNSString(const NSString* str){
```

to:

```
void getNSString(const NSString* str){
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. You should get a compiler warning about this, too.

Comment: Upon reflection, the one thing that you might want to add to this answer is an emphasis that **undefined** is completely different **nothing**. A function that specifies a return will always return something. Depending on the structure, it may sometimes be `nil`, but even `nil` is something.

Answer (score 0):

cocoa/objective c does this way.... I also face this type problem before,

for example :

```
-(NSObject*) someMethod () 
{  ...

   NSString* result =@"some value"; 
   // because too busy ,I just forgot write the return statement during dev :)
}
```

although nothing was return like above code, but the app also can return the result value ....

that is very funny....